# php and mysql query trouble - query isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to create a table of users that are part of a group but I can't seem to get it working. The list is stored in a column so that each userid # is separated by a "~". For example, if users 1,2 and 3 are attending the column would show "1~2~3". This is what I use explode for.

I'm getting the following error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in" which is for the line where $friend is defined.

```
$attendingUsers = mysql_query("Select acceptedInvites from events where eventID = ".$_GET['eventID']." ");
    while($friend = mysql_fetch_array($attendingUsers)){
                $users = $friend['acceptedInvites'];
                $userExplode = explode("~",$users);
            for($i=0; $i<count($userExplode);$i++){
                echo $userExplode[$i]; //displays the userid number properly so I know this is working
                $friendInfo = mysql_query("select (userid,username) from users where userid = '". $userExplode[$i]."' ");;
                $friend = mysql_fetch_array($friendInfo);
                echo '<table><tr><td><a href="profile.php?userid=' . $friend['userid'] . '">' . $friend['username'] . '</a></td>';
                }
            }
```

I'm starting to think it's something to do with $friendInfo because when I echo it nothing is displayed (usually would say array).

Comment: Nice sql injection hole. Hope you like the truck someone'll drive through it  and park in the middle of your server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems here. The primary problem you're experiencing is that you have no error handling and a syntax error in your query.  There should be no parentheses around the select list columns:

```
$friendInfo = mysql_query("select userid, username from users where userid = '". $userExplode[$i]."' ");
//-------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Some basic error handling will surface these errors:

```
$friendInfo = mysql_query("select userid, username from users where userid = '". $userExplode[$i]."' ");
if (!$friendInfo) {
  // error!
  echo mysql_error();
}
else {
  $friend = mysql_fetch_array(....);
}
```

You must escape the input parameters against SQL injection, rather than use them directly in the query. That is most easily done with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

```
$attendingUsers = mysql_query("Select acceptedInvites from events where eventID = ". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['eventID'])." ");
```

You can improve this algorithm a bit by replacing the `for` loop with a query that uses an `IN()` clause.  Instead of looping over all the friends, do one query by imploding the array into a comma-separated list:

```
$userExplode = explode("~", $users);
// Implode them together with commas
// Don't forget to call mysql_real_escape_string() on these if necessary
$friendlist = implode(",", $userExplode);
// Actually, you could just do $friendlist = str_replace("~", ",", $users)
// and avoid doing either explode() or implode()...

// Then query with an IN () clause...
$friendInfo = mysql_query("select userid, username from users where userid IN ($friendlist)");
```

Now rather than performing the query in a loop, you only need to fetch in a loop. This is far more efficient than querying again and again.

Comment: Wow, such a simple mistake. I can't believe I didn't notice that, I guess it's time to take a break for the day. Thanks for the help!